# commit edit doesn't call setOneditCommit

Tags: combobox, javafx, tableview

I have 1 issue in my project.
I'd like to have a tableColum built with comboBox, and for this i use:

```
tableColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(cbValues));
```

it works but like DOC says:

> By default, the ComboBoxTableCell is rendered as a Label when not being edited, and as a ComboBox when in editing mode.

but i want to see the comboBox every time, so i build this code

```
tableColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Ambientale, Integer>, TableCell<Ambientale, Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<Ambientale, Integer> call(TableColumn<Ambientale, Integer> param) {
            return new ComboBoxCell(cbValues);
        }
    });
```

and my ComboBoxCell is:

```
class ComboBoxCell extends TableCell<Ambientale, Integer> implements Callback<Object, Object>{
 private ComboBox combo;


public ComboBoxCell() {
    combo = new ComboBox();
}

public ComboBoxCell(ObservableList items) {
    combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.setItems(items);
    combo.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println(" it's works");
            commitEdit((Integer)combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()); 
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        combo.getSelectionModel().select(item);
        setGraphic(combo);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);

    }
}

@Override
public Object call(Object param) {
    return new ComboBoxCell();
} 
}
```

the issue is here!

```
class ComboBoxCell extends TableCell<Ambientale, Integer> implements Callback<Object, Object>{
 private ComboBox combo;


public ComboBoxCell() {
    combo = new ComboBox();
}

public ComboBoxCell(ObservableList items) {
    combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.setItems(items);
    combo.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println(" it's works");
            commitEdit((Integer)combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()); 
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        combo.getSelectionModel().select(item);
        setGraphic(combo);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);

    }
}

@Override
public Object call(Object param) {
    return new ComboBoxCell();
}
```

}
commitEdit(...) doesn't call:

```
tableColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Ambientale, Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Ambientale, Integer> t) { //aggiornare database cella singola
            System.out.println("not called");
            //other stuffs
        }
    });
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: I guess that is because you are not setting the onEditCommit on the right tablecolumn. Try tableColumn.setOnEditCommit(...);

Comment: edited, it was a little mistake on this question, not on the code. but tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, i don't know why but it works.
i've added this on my ComboBoxCell

```
combo.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                    } else {
                        commitEdit((Integer)combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                    }
                }
    });
```